# Dealing with errors in BufferedMediaTypeFormatter derived class

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, mediatypeformatter

I am implementing a BufferedMediaTypeFormatter for use in a Web API project, but I can't find any details of how to handle errors when overriding `ReadFromStream` on BufferedMediaTypeTormatter.

I know that I should be writing errors to the `IFormatterLogger.LogError` method, but what should I return if the input is invalid? Should I return null? Or throw an exception? If so, which exception should be thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the kind of user experience you are looking for.

If you throw an exception, Web API would short-circuit the processing of request and returns a `500 Internal Server` response (with or without the exception details based on your `HttpConfiguration.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy` settings).

If you log errors via the `IFormatterLogger.LogError` (you can return null in this case), then the request processing is *not* short-circuited and a user would need to check for the `ModelState` validity to figure out if there are any errors.

Comment: Thanks, I will go for the latter.